# Assigning method result to variable

Tags: c#, variables, object, memory

Does using a method result without a variable use the same amount of memory as not doing so?

For example, is this:

```
public int A()
{
    ...
    return a;
}
if(A() == 1)
...
```

Still going to use the same amount of memory as:

```
public int A()
{
    ...
    return a;
}

int a = A();
if(a == 1)
...
```

I know the difference is relatively miniscule, but should I be trying to do this if I'm performing a lot of functions on different, large byte arrays?

Comment: Where's the void result here? Your method returns an `int`.

Comment: the function is called, a value is returned. that value will simply be destroyed/discarded once the `==` test is completed, since it wasn't assigned anywhere. ideally, you'd only use "half" the memory, e.g. the value stays in a cpu register instead of being copied to memory somewhere.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  Write it so that the code is easily read and let the compiler optimize such minute things.  If it turns out to be a measurable performance issue, then post the real code you've written and ask for specific advice then.

Comment: Do you think "void" means "method"?

Comment: No, sorry everyone. Mid afternoon typos, man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you meant `if(A() == 1)` vs.:

```
var a = A();
if (a == 1)
```

The answer is complicated and depends on optimization settings, JIT version, bitness and CPU architecture.

For primitive types there usually is no difference. If this was a large struct there might be a difference, especially considering that the current JITs are awful at optimizing structs.